# Get the size of an array if the input array's element match atleast one

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to count the views of videos. I have the following structure.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("some_id")
    views:[
        { userId:1, groupId:[1,2,4] },
        { userId:2, groupId:[2,4] },
        { userId:1, groupId:[3,5] }
    ]
}
```

I just need to count if both arrays (`views.groupId` and input array) have common elements, increase the count by one.
If the input array is is `[1,3,5]` then the no of views is 2. (first object has element 1 and third object has elements 3,5)

I wrote the following code, but it gives wrong answer.

```
{
    $project: {
        views: {
            $size: {
                $ifNull: [{
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$views',
                            as: 'views',
                            cond: {
                                $setIntersection: [
                                    '$$views.groupId',
                                    [1,3,5]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    []
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I spent more time to solve it by myself, but no luck today. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a **valid condition** to the `$filter` operator.

In your case, if you return the `Number` value in the `cond` parameter, it will convert it into `Boolean` with [this convention](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#convert-to-bool):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      views: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$views",
                as: "view",
                cond: {
                  $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                      "$$view.groupId",
                      [ 1, 3, 5]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uy4USREBY9Q) | [Alternative $gt](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AqSm4uk7bbb)

Comment: wow, this is so easy, I think I made a mistake, `$setIntersection` returns the elements, not size

Answer (score 0):

The approach with `$setIntersection` and `$size` is correct but since you want to transform an array into a single value it's better to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html). Additionally the usage of [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) ensures that the value added in each iteration will by `1` or `0` (`1` at most):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            views: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$views",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                $min: [ 1, { $size: { $setIntersection: [ "$$this.groupId", [ 1,3,5 ] ]  } } ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tvVBZ3_ILeL)

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks for your answer